# jsf with Ajax having issues with mapping

Tags: ajax, jsf, alias, ajax4jsf, tomahawk

I have the following method in the manager which is called on blur of the patientId text field on a jsf page

```
private Patient patientData; //also have get and set 

public void search(ActionEvent actionEvent){
                 String aPatientId   = (String)getPatientInputTextField().getSubmittedValue();
                 Session s = null;
              try{
               s = HibernateUtil.getSession();
               StringBuffer sql =new StringBuffer("  from Patient p ");
               if(!(aPatientId == null || aPatientId.length() ==0 )){
                sql.append(where);
                sql.append(" p.pid=:patientId ");
                pidflag=true;
               }
               Query qList1 = s.createQuery(sql.toString());
               Integer patientId = aPatientId == null || aPatientId.length() == 0? 0 : Integer.valueOf(aPatientId);
               qList1.setInteger("patientId", patientId);
               int size = qList1.list().size();
               if(size > 0 ){
                 patientData = (Patient)qList1.list().get(0);
               }else if(size ==0 ){
                 System.err.println("NO MATCH FOUND");
                }
             }catch(Exception exception){
                 exception.printStackTrace();
             }
    }
```

I am having the following code in the JSF

```
<t:inputText id="patientId" binding="#{Manager.patientInputTextField}" 
        value="#{patient.pid}" readonly="#{readonly}">

<a4j:support event = "onblur" immediate="true"
         actionListener = "#{Manager.search}"  reRender = "firstName,lastName,phoneNum"/>
</t:inputText>
<t:inputText id='lastName'  value="#{patient.lastName}" />
<t:inputText id='firstName' value="#{patient.firstName}"/>
<t:inputText id='phoneNum'  value="#{patient.phoneNum}" />
```

when I check the patientData object in the managerI get the values of firstName,lastName & phonenumber without any issues the data is been returned by the manager

The above JSP is an include Jsp (info.jsp) which is been included in the main.jsp

```
<f:view>
<h:messages ></h:messages>
<body>
<h:form id="headerinclude">
    <t:aliasBeansScope>
        <t:aliasBean alias="#{patient}" value="#{Manager.patientData}" />
          <f:subview id="billingView">
            <%@ include file="info.jsp"%>
          </f:subview>
    </t:aliasBeansScope>
```

Now I am not able to render the values for firstName, lastName and phoneNumber which is returned by the patientData object in the manager

Any help / pointers in solving this would be appreciated trying to resolve this since a week now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not doing the following in the Manager due to which the values were not setted in the JSP

patientInputTextField.setSubmittedValue(null);
        patientFNameTextField.setSubmittedValue(null);
        patientLNameTextField.setSubmittedValue(null);
        patientPhoneNumTextField.setSubmittedValue(null);